# Perturbation theory with eigenvalue-dependent perturbation

Tags: perturbation-theory, dispersion

Suppose I have an operator equation of the sort
$$ 
[H_0 + H_1(\lambda)]\mathbf{v} = \lambda\mathbf{v}.
$$
Here, $H_0$ defines unperturbed eigensolutions $\{\lambda_0, \mathbf{v}_0\}$, and $H_1(\lambda)$ is considered a perturbation. Note that $H_1(\lambda)$ is a nonlinear (or dispersive) perturbation which depends on the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Now, I'm interested in the leading-order correction to $\lambda_0$ due to this perturbation, i.e. if $\lambda = \lambda_0 + \lambda_1 + \ldots$, I'm seeking $\lambda_1$. If we just proceed with the usual program of perturbation theory, we'd end up with the expression 
$$
\lambda_1 = \frac{\langle \mathbf{v}_0| H_1(\lambda)|\mathbf{v}_0\rangle}{\langle\mathbf{v}_0|\mathbf{v}_0\rangle}.
$$

Unfortunately, this is of course not really a closed equation due to the presence of $\lambda$ in $H_1(\lambda)$. We might do a pole approximation, and simply swap $H_1(\lambda)$ for $H_1(\lambda_0)$; which appears to me to be very reasonable in the context of a strict first-order approach.

What I'm really interested in, however, is to know the implications of instead swapping $H_1(\lambda)$ for e.g. $H_1(\lambda_0 + \lambda_1)$? Proceeding with that would mean the inclusion of a "dispersion"-term $\lambda_1\langle \mathbf{v}_0|\frac{\partial H_1}{\partial\lambda}(\lambda_0)|\mathbf{v}_0\rangle$.

More generally, there are situations where I might actually know $\lambda$ (e.g. from measurements) and instead seek to infer the matrix element.

**To summarize:** I'm looking for keywords, insight, and/or related literature on the implications of the sort of approach outlined above. I'm imagining that this could have been treated e.g. in the context of nonlinear eigenvalue problems and lambda-matrices?

Comment: Your equation is basically this scalar equation $\lambda_1=F(\lambda_1)$. Why not use a Picard iteration on it: $\lambda_1^{k+1}=F(\lambda_1^k)$. If the nonlinearity is not strong it will converge well; and you can always add a relaxation factor there to guarantee convergence, if you start close enough to the root.

Comment: I can't/don't want to employ a numerical approach here - the use-case is to infer the (unknown) matrix elements from measured data of response to perturbation; in short, I need this to stay relatively close to traditional perturbation theory.